# Como faço um insert num relacionamento ternário?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

Estou criando este modelo contudo não sei se ele esta correto. Pois tenho conhecimentos básicos em banco de dados.

Como faço um insert em um relacionamento ternário que acontece em Fornecedor - Fornecedores_has_produto - Produto?

[image: DB]

Comment: Como você pretende inserir esses dados? Você tem uma camada de aplicação (e se tem, em que linguagem) ou pretende/precisa fazer isso somente via SQL/stored procedure? Por fim, os IDs de `fornecedor` e `produto` são inteiros simples (que você atribui) ou de auto-incremento (ex.: `serial`)?

Comment: Vou utilizar PHP, os IDs eu defini como auto-incremento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu relacionamento me parece correto sim. Você cadastra os fornecedores, os produtos, e quando quer associar um fornecedor com um produto (numa relação muitos-para-muitos) você utiliza os seus IDs na tabela de interseção (`fornecedor_has_produto`).

Se você não sabe os IDs, simplesmente acabou de inserir um fornecedor e/ou produto e quer obter o ID auto-atribuído pelo banco, use a função [`LAST_INSERT_ID`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id). Normalmente, a biblioteca que você estiver usando para conectar ao banco (ex.: **PDO**, **mysqli**) terá uma função para fazer isso pra você (já que é uma funcionalidade comum).

Um exemplo (simplificado) usando **PDO**:

```
/* Conecta ao banco de dados */
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=mysql", $username, $password);

/* Insere um fornecedor */
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into fornecedor(nome, cnpj, ...) values(:nome, :cnpj, ...);");
$stmt.bindParam(":nome", $nome_do_fornecedor);
$stmt.bindParam(":cnpj", $cnpj_do_fornecedor);
...
$stmt->execute();

/* Obtém o ID do fornecedor inserido */
$id_fornecedor = $dbh->lastInsertId()

/* Insere um produto */
...

/* Obtém o ID do produto inserido */
$id_produto = $dbh->lastInsertId()

/* Relaciona o fornecedor com o produto */
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("insert into fornecedor_has_produto(fornecedor_id, produto_id) values(:fornecedor, :produto);");
$stmt.bindParam(":fornecedor", $id_fornecedor, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt.bindParam(":produto", $id_produto, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

(Não tenho experiência prática com PHP, montei esse exemplo a partir de outros exemplos online, mas deve ter dado pra demonstrar o que precisa ser feito. Se quiser um exemplo com **mysqli** em vez disso, posso fazer.)

Comment: Valeu vou fazer uns testes aqui.